# Testing DSL developed in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

I'm working on a DSL using Kotlin, and I'm wondering about the best approach for testing it.

The top level element is an article, with a class, and a top level function for the DSL

```
class Article {
    val children = mutableListOf<DocumentSection>()
}

inline fun article(init: Article.() -> Unit): Article {
    val article = Article()
    article.init()
    return article
}
```

In the article I have a nested section.

```
class Section(val parent: Document, val title: String)  {
    val children = mutableListOf<Element>()
}

fun DocumentSection.text(text: String) = this.children.add(TextElement(this, text))
```

And an extension function to add a section to the article

```
inline fun Article.section(title: String, init: Section.() -> Unit): Section {
    val section = Section(this, title)
    section.init()
    this.children.add(section)
    return section
}
```

## Testing the implementation

Now when testing the article, it is simple, but when testing nested items of the DSL, it becomes very verbose. And in this case I'm also relying on the article

```
class SectionDslTest : DescribeSpec() {
    init {
        describe("a section without content") {
            val title = "section title"

            val article = article {
                section(title) {}
            }

            it("should have only the title set") {
                article.children.first().title shouldBe title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case it would be best to just test `section.title shouldBe title`

The problem here of course are the extension functions. (Which are one of the best features of Kotlin, don't get me wrong).

I have also tested the `Section` class, which can be done just fine. But I believe that we should test what will be exposed to the user, and everything else can be a nice bonus, or it can even be bad if the extra tests are working agains you.

Anyway, here is the test on the `Section` class.

```
class SectionTest : DescribeSpec() {
    init {
        describe("a document section with some text") {
            val parent = Article()
            val title = "section title"
            val section = Section(parent, title)

            it("should have the parent article set") {
                section.parent shouldBe parent
            }

            it("should have the title set") {
                section.title shouldBe title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best approach to test this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Your code seems to work fine. Or is it just about the verbosity?

Comment: @AndreasVolkmann it is about the verbosity. The code does work just fine. Especially when the DSL will become more layered, the tests will become more and more verbose.